# What to do when there are multiple pursuers

Tags: halacha, murder, rodef, halacha-lemoshe-misinai

We know that if there is one (a rodef) who is actively attacking another person in the hopes of killing him, one is allowed to restrain, maim, or even kill the rodef. However, what happens if there are multiple rodefs attacking one person. Let us assume that the watcher cannot take down all of the rodefs before the rodefs kill their victim. Is it best to kill as many rodefs as you can, or is it best to not do anything since anything you do will not make a difference?

Comment: Wouldn't this be based on the question if a rodef gets killed because he's inherently chayiv misa or if it's only in order to save the nirdaf? If he's chayiv misa then kill as many as you can, if it's only to save the nirdaf then since he won't be saved, there's no heter to kill the rodef. Reb Chaim in Chiddushim 103 and in Sefer Hilchos Retzicha brings the two sides and says it's only in order to save the nirdaf.

Comment: To be fair, the Brisker Rav says according to the Rambam, a rodef is considered a dead man walking, and your patur if you kill him, even if it doesn't effect saving the nirdaf.

Comment: I think a bigger question with multiple pursuers is endangering one's own life (as they might turn on him, making him the victim). To that effect, the bigger question would be: How far may/must one go in endangering one's own life, in order to save another from a _rodef_?

Comment: "Let us assume that the watcher cannot take down all of the rodefs before the rodefs kill their victim." What gives you the right to assume that?

Comment: Just wondering the exact parameters of the case. If there are 10 people chasing one person, it is almost imposible that ALL 10 will kill him. They may all contribute, but only 1 or 2 will deal the final blow and kill him. Therefore only some of the group are rodfim while the others would not be considered a rodef. SInce there is no way of knowing who will be the rodef, they are all Safek Rodef, in which case it is not clear that you can kill any of them.

Comment: @Chatzkel, they are called "Rodfim" not "Retzichim" b/c they are *chasing* him not b/c they are guaranteed to kill him! Anyone who chases someone else with intent to kill is a rodef, whether or not they succeed. According to your logic, if the someone kills the rodef, then, since the rodef never succeeded in killing anyone, they therefore were never a rodef, and that person is now a murderer!

Comment: @yogazefish, I would honestly like to say that as it is never clear exactly if one will die or not, you can kill them to improve your chances. However, you could just say the case is where it was certain the nirdaf would die, although that isn't very realistic.